# What does the -p flag do in "mkdir -p"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What does the `-p` flag do in `mkdir -p`?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The `-p` flag will create nested directories, but only if they don't exist already.

For example, suppose you have a directory `/foo` that you have write permissions for.

```
mkdir -p /foo/bar/baz  # creates bar and baz within bar under existing /foo
```

It is also an *idempotent* operation, because if you run the same command over again, you will not get an error, but nothing will be created.

Answer (score 7):

This `-p` flag allows a parent folder to be created along with the nested folder.

For example:

```
mkdir directory/nested_directory
```

it would return the following error : `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘directory/nested_directory’: No such file or directory`

But if you use `-p` such as:

```
mkdir -p directory/nested_directory
```

It will create both directory and it's nested nested_directory folders successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: I think this answer adds clarity to the case when both the parent and the child directories do not exist. This is a superset of the "nested", child directory not existing.

Answer (score 1):

It actually does two different things.

1. No error if existing

   - Prints *no errors* like `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘<dir>’: File exists`
2. Make parent directories as needed

   - You may create *nested* directories like `mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3`
   - The containing directories (in example: `dir1`, `dir2`) will be unaffected by file mode options (`-m`)